# Troubles iterating through list in python

Tags: python, json, list, loops, enumerate

In python, I have a list called "list" that looks like the following:

```
[{'lastname': 'lname1', 'firstname': 'fname1', 'shortname': 'SN1'},
{'lastname': 'lname2', 'firstname': 'fname2', 'shortname': 'SN2'},
{'lastname': 'lname3', 'firstname': 'fname3', 'shortname': 'SN3'}]
```

I need to be able to access each of these attributes, for EACH item in the list. So I have to get the lastname of each user, firstname of each user, etc

As this is a list, I have been trying to do it as follows:

```
for idx in enumerate(list):
        print(list[idx])
```

But I get an error saying the list indices must be integers, not tuples.

So trying this:

```
for idx in enumerate(list):
        print(idx)
```

I get output like this:

```
(0, {'lastname': 'lname1', 'firstname': 'fname1', 'shortname': 'SN1'})
(1, {'lastname': 'lname2', 'firstname': 'fname2', 'shortname': 'SN2'})
(2, {'lastname': 'lname3', 'firstname': 'fname3', 'shortname': 'SN3'})
```

All I want is to be able to get the index, so I can iterate through each list item and say

```
firstname = list[idx]["firstname"]
lastname = list[idx]["lastname"]
```

And so on.

Note: If I say something like

```
print(list[0]["firstname"])
```

it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong? Or what do I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't name your list `list`, as this masks a literal in Python.

Comment: I'll be sure to change that!

Comment: A better way to use enumerate would be like this:
`for idx, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 6):

```
for item in list:
    item['firstname']
```

Although this is a bad idea to use the name `list` for your list, as this is already the name of the constructor for lists in Python's standard lib.

`enumerate` is usefull in case you *need* the index of the item in the list. It yields a `tuple` containing the index of the item and the item itself (as you experienced for yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike JavaScript, iterating over a sequence in Python yields elements, not indexes.

```
print idx['lastname']
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists indeces are integers.

```
>>> x = ['test','test2','test3']
>>> x[1]
'test2'
```

What you have is a list dictionaries. So what you would have to do is iterate through the list and through the dictionary. Like so:

```
>>> x = [{'cat':'lol'},{'tigers':'lions'}]
>>> for z in x:
...  for d in z:
...   print z[d]
...
lol
lions
```

So if you just want the name:

```
for d in list:
 print d['firstname']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `enumerate`, Use it when you need the indexes of the elements, which you don't here..

What you seem to want to do is:

```
for di in mylist: # for .. in ... : Iterates over the contents of ...
   for elem in di:
      print elem,':', di[elem]
```

or

```
for di in mylist:
    print di['firstname'], di['lastname']
```